# MIN and MAX Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, max, min

I have a table with a sales column and date of that sales column, and I want to select the min and max and the date of this min and max for response a single max with its date and single min with its date, in Oracle, but I don't know how do it, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you get us the table structure with some sample result which you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Explanation it looks like you need something like below:

```
1) SELECT Sales , date FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Sales = ( SELECT MIN(Sales) FROM TABLE_NAME)

2) SELECT Sales , date FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Sales = ( SELECT MAX(Sales) FROM TABLE_NAME)
```

In single Query

```
    SELECT Sales , date FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Sales = ( SELECT MIN(Sales) FROM TABLE_NAME)

    UNION 

    SELECT Sales , date FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Sales = ( SELECT MAX(Sales) FROM

 TABLE_NAME)
```

Comment: Yes, but I want a single query

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember the UNION operator